# Implement multiprocessing in Python with a message passing interface

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, message-passing

I'm trying to convert some JavaScript code into Python, but JavaScript runs code asynchronously and has an easy event emitter-listener function to communicate between different instances. Is there any similar way to do this in Python?

I've tried using Process (from multiprocessing) but I couldn't find an easy message passing implementation anywhere

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing


def do_some_work(inputs):

    # Time consuming task
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # Some output
    return f"some response for input {inputs}"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Create a pool of 4 workers (can be more of course)
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:

        # Assign a list of work to the pool of workers and get the results
        result = pool.map(do_some_work, [f"input_{i}" for i in range(100)])

    # Show the results
    print(result)
```

Output:

```py
['some response for input input_0', 'some response for input input_1', 'some response for input input_2', 'some response for input input_3', 'some response for input input_4', 'some response for input input_5', 'some response for input input_6', 'some response for input input_7', 'some response for input input_8', 'some response for input input_9', 'some response for input input_10', 'some response for input input_11', 'some response for input input_12', 'some response for input input_13', 'some response for input input_14', 'some response for input input_15', 'some response for input input_16', 'some response for input input_17', 'some response for input input_18', 'some response for input input_19', 'some response for input input_20', 'some response for input input_21', 'some response for input input_22', 'some response for input input_23', 'some response for input input_24', 'some response for input input_25', 'some response for input input_26', 'some response for input input_27', 'some response for input input_28', 'some response for input input_29', 'some response for input input_30', 'some response for input input_31', 'some response for input input_32', 'some response for input input_33', 'some response for input input_34', 'some response for input input_35', 'some response for input input_36', 'some response for input input_37', 'some response for input input_38', 'some response for input input_39', 'some response for input input_40', 'some response for input input_41', 'some response for input input_42', 'some response for input input_43', 'some response for input input_44', 'some response for input input_45', 'some response for input input_46', 'some response for input input_47', 'some response for input input_48', 'some response for input input_49', 'some response for input input_50', 'some response for input input_51', 'some response for input input_52', 'some response for input input_53', 'some response for input input_54', 'some response for input input_55', 'some response for input input_56', 'some response for input input_57', 'some response for input input_58', 'some response for input input_59', 'some response for input input_60', 'some response for input input_61', 'some response for input input_62', 'some response for input input_63', 'some response for input input_64', 'some response for input input_65', 'some response for input input_66', 'some response for input input_67', 'some response for input input_68', 'some response for input input_69', 'some response for input input_70', 'some response for input input_71', 'some response for input input_72', 'some response for input input_73', 'some response for input input_74', 'some response for input input_75', 'some response for input input_76', 'some response for input input_77', 'some response for input input_78', 'some response for input input_79', 'some response for input input_80', 'some response for input input_81', 'some response for input input_82', 'some response for input input_83', 'some response for input input_84', 'some response for input input_85', 'some response for input input_86', 'some response for input input_87', 'some response for input input_88', 'some response for input input_89', 'some response for input input_90', 'some response for input input_91', 'some response for input input_92', 'some response for input input_93', 'some response for input input_94', 'some response for input input_95', 'some response for input input_96', 'some response for input input_97', 'some response for input input_98', 'some response for input input_99']
```